# How to make a QDockWidget not resizable by mouse?

Tags: c++, qt

How could I make a QDockWidget such that the user is not able to drag the boundary of the QDockWidget to resize it?

Comment: I think that it is not possible when your widgets are docked. For undocked widgets you may try `setFixedSize` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `setSizePolicy`. Something like

```
dock->setSizePolicy(QsizePolicy::Fixed);
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems it doesnt work, the user could still drag to change its size.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, can set the size policy of the widget in dock widget to fixed.

```
inner_widget=QWidget()
inner_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

dock=QDockWidget("")
dock.setWidget(inner_widget)
```

I'm using PyQt with Qt 5.15.